# when does this anonymous callback function run when doing some ajax stuff?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I just started learning ajax and I just can't get the concept of the anonymous callback functions used in the example.

```
function getData(dataSource, divID) 
  { 
    if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
      var obj = document.getElementById(divID); 
      XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource); 

      XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
      { 
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
          XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
            obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; 
        } 
      } 

      XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null); 
    }
  }
```

when does the anonymous function trigger here? does javascript read this line by line?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking, exactly?  I can't quite tell ...

Comment: hi, i'm just not sure when the anonymous function gets processed.

Comment: It gets processed when there's a state change of the request.  The only state you usually need to handle is the **ready** state, because that means you have your data back from the server.

Comment: thanks for the help man. appreciate it.

Comment: Just to clarify a misconception. The function you assign to `onreadystatechange` need not be anonymous. You may give it any name you want. You may assign it a `FunctionExpression` or a `FunctionDeclaration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your code, you are:

1. building a request object
2. you assign a callback to that object
3. you send the request

the function you assigned to `XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange` is an example of an anonymous function that will get executed once `readyState` changes. to do a rough comparison, it's like adding an `onchange` to a `<select>` - when value *changes*, execute assigned *anonymous function*

anonymous functions are very important, and one of it's uses it to define a set of "things to do", basically handing a "todo" list to the another operation. then that operation will execute it when needed, in this case `onreadystatechange`.

your code is also an example of an "asynchonous operation". The code gets run top to bottom. The callback is just "assigned" and thus not executed. Once you send the request, ***it will not wait*** for the response at this point. It will be like a background operation, while the rest of the code after it gets executed.

Once the value of `readyState` changes, the function you just assigned to `XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange` gets executed. the conditions

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200
```

in that function determines if the request is complete (4) and the page is ok (200). if so, the response is ready for use.

Comment: The function is executed multiple times (every time the `readystate` changes), not just when the request is successful

Comment: oh yeah, if forgot that. updating

Comment: hey @joseph, thanks for the answer man. i got it now. and PHIL, it does that everytime the state changes? gee, it should not get included with some trash then because that would really take some resources.

Comment: to be exact, the anonymous function is called whenever the `readyState` attribute of the request changes, which means the function will be called more than once

Comment: @simon the part in the anon function `XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200` determines if the request is a success (afaik, 4 meaning request complete and 200 meaning the page is ok)

Comment: yeah, i guess i need to review the types of statuses then because i think there is a lot. :D thanks for the tip man

Answer (score 3):

Functions in Javascript are first class objects, which means they can be passed around like any other variable.

The line

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() { }
```

is setting the `onreadystatechange` property of the `XMLHttpRequestObject` object to that function. If you check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#Properties), you'll see that this function "is called whenever the `readyState` attribute changes"

Comment: hey man, thanks for the help. seeing things the first time gets baffled. anyway appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 2):

When you set `XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange` you are actually changing the method of the class, so the function isn't executed when you are setting it, but later when the ready state is changed...

The function is called everytime the readyState is changed, so if you set a counter there

```
var counter = 0;

XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() { console.log(counter++) };
```

and examine the console.log you'll see that is called as many times as the onreadystatechange ( it's an event that triggers the anonymouse function )

Although I read that you are just learning javascript and AJAX, I suggest see something for cross-browser support as jQuery, Zepto and other...

Comment: hey man, thanks for the help. yeah, i also just knew that there were two versions of javascript. and because of that, the creation of the ajax xmlhttpobject gets kinds dirty because adding ifs for the type of browser would become necessary. anyway appreciate the man, i would also check out that zepto thing

Comment: DOM manipulation libraries like jQuery and Zepto aren't version Two of javascript or smth. They just wrap the XMLHttpRequestObject for cross-browser support and portability. In fact I think that you'll need a lot of time to make this work on every other browser, but with the libraries ( especially for XMLHttpRequest ) the things are already written for cross-browsing. You will have error callbacks, success callbacks and you won't worry about different readyStates and responseStatuses

Comment: nice! if that would make the job easier, then I guess I need to put it on my to do list then. thanks for the tip man.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#The_onreadystatechange_event_listener):

> If the open method of the XMLHttpRequest object was invoked with the
>   third parameter **set to true for an asynchronous request**, the
>   onreadystatechange event listener will be automatically invoked for
>   each of the following actions that change the readyState property of
>   the XMLHttpRequest object.

That means that the callback is called whenever the readystate property changes. Since the call is asynchronous you cannot know when this will happen (because it basically depends on server's response time).

Comment: hey man, thanks for the answer. i get it now, so when the server responds then the anonymous function runs and then the target object should be manipulated by DOM. appreciate the help man. :D

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll take you through a step by step explanation of AJAX:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;     // create a new HTTP Request
request.open("GET", "/resource.txt"); // set the method as GET and specify the URL to request for
request.onreadystatechange = handle;  // attach a handler which is called when the ready state of the request changes
request.send();                       // dispatch the HTTP Request

/*
    function to call when the ready state of the request changes
*/ 

function handle() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        alert(request.responseText);  // if the ready state is 4 (complete) and the server sends a status of 200 (OK) then alert the contents of resource.txt which is stored in request.responseText
    }
}
```

Now to understand:

1. AJAX is used to communicate with the server.
2. To communicate with the server we need to send it a message (an `XMLHttpRequest`).
3. In the message we specify the method the message uses (`GET`, `POST`, etc.) You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).
4. We need to specify the destination address of the message (the URL). In this case it's `/resource.txt`.
5. Now that we have made the letter we actually send it. It's like putting it into a mailbox.
6. Now it's the problem of the post office (in this case the browser) to deliver the mail.
7. However if we want to know the status of the mail (the `readyState`) we need to tell the browser to notify us whenever it changes.
8. To be notified we simply add a function to `onreadystatechange`. Now whenever the `readyState` of the message changes the browser will automatically call the function.

These are the ready states of the message:

1. 0 (uninitialized) - request not initialized
2. 1 (loading) - server connection established
3. 2 (loaded) - request received
4. 3 (interactive) - processing request
5. 4 (complete) - request finished and response is ready

Alright, now to understand what's happening:

1. When we write a message but do not send it the `readyState` is `0` because the request is not initialized (i.e. it's not been sent or put into the mailbox).
2. After we put the message in the mailbox, the browser tries to send the message to the server. At this point the `readyState` becomes `1`.
3. When the whole message is delivered then the `readyState` becomes `2`.
4. The server then writes the reply to the message and in the body of the message it puts the content you requested. When the server is writing the reply the `readyState` becomes `3`.
5. Finally when the reply reaches us the `readyState` changes to `4`.

Every time the `readyState` changes, the browser fires the `onreadystatechange` function that you supplied it to notify you that an event has occured. Simple right?

In conclusion, if you want to read more about status codes go to this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).